# First day of the month

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

```
WHERE to_date(smz_loanservicing.as_of_date) = last_day(add_months(current_date, -1))
```

The above will provide data only if the loanservicing.as_of_date occurs on the very last day of the month.

Last month (May 31 2020) the last day of the month fell on Sunday.

Is there a way to get the the first day of the month and say if this particular date occurs between the first and last day of the month, show the date?  Essentially there were no activities on Sunday so the data was missed.
I tried

```
to_date(smz_loanservicing.as_of_date) 
    between first_day(add_month(current_date,-1)) 
    and last_day(add_months(current_date, -1))`
```

However I get syntax error.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: is this oracle?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `as_of_date`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to check if your date column belongs to the current month.

The syntax you use would work in Oracle, so let me assume this is the database that you are running. I also assume that column `as_of_date` is of datatype `date` (or `timestamp`).

What you ask for should be as simple as:

```
where
    as_of_date >= trunc(current_date, 'mm') 
    and as_of_date < add_months(trunc(current_date, 'mm'), 1)
```

Actually, your syntax would also work in Snowflake - and so would the above code.

Note: if `as_of_date` actually is a string, then you need `to_date()` to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just truncate the date to the month, then you don’t need the know the first or last day.

```
where trunc(as_of_date, ‘MM’) = trunc(current_date, ‘MM’)
```